# how to change this model output from float to string?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Layer
import keras.backend as K

np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

class Round(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Round, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_output(self, train=False):
        X = self.get_input(train)
        return K.round(X)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {"name": self.__class__.__name__}
        base_config = super(Round, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))


def build_and_train_mlp_network(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):

    nb_epoch = 1000
    batch_size = 4

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Round()) # return K.round(X)

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)  # or binary_crossentropy

    model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              verbose=0,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":

    X_test = X_train = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]])

    y_train = y_test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

    model = build_and_train_mlp_network(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    print(model.predict(X_test))
```

how to change this model output from float to string ?

output is `[[0.9999342 ] [0.99991477] [0.99989116] [0.9998405 ]]`

now i change

```
y_train = y_test = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

how to make output ( model.predict(X_test) ) to be string ?

Comment: what is the purpose of the round layer? Just to get a even number?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of guessing involved: i assume your "round" layers purpose is to get an output which is a integer number. However, that way you are most likely killing the gradient in the SGD.

To avoid the problem in the gradient you should do it as a post processing step. Hence, I'd recommend to alter the neural network the following way:

```py
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
#    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

The linear activation to achieve numbers larger than `1`. this function is the reason you got `[[0.9999342 ] [0.99991477] [0.99989116] [0.9998405 ]]`
 Afterwards you can post process the outputs

```
print(np.round(model.predict(X_test)))
```

or to map to characters you can use

```
maps = ['foo','a','b','c','d','bar'] # ugly what about -1...6,... etc
[maps[int(round(i))] for i in  model.predict(X_test).flatten()]
```

With the functional API you can actually push the rounding into the NN. I had to re-write your layer a bit

```py
class Round(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Round, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self,X):
        print(X)
        return K.round(X)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {"name": self.__class__.__name__}
        base_config = super(Round, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))


r = Round()(outputs)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
modelr = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=r)
modelr.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
modelr.predict(X_test)
```

Having said that I think you have a fundamental flaw in your model. The model assumes that there is a ordering in the characters. Which means that `b` is something in between `a` and `c`. This is true from the perspective of the alphabet, however, wrong in the sense of semantic.

Therefore, you should use the standard one-hot encoding approach. Also the problem which unmappel characters, e.g., `foo`,`bar` wouldn't happen. Check the standard TF/Keras Mnist example

You can than build your model the following way

```py
from keras.utils import np_utils

num_classes=5 # sorry but we need zero

def build_and_train_mlp_network(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):

    nb_epoch = 1000
    batch_size = 4

    inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
    d1 = Dense(2)(inputs)
    a1 = Activation('sigmoid')(d1)
    d2 = Dense(num_classes)(a1)
    a2 = Activation(activation='softmax')(d2)


    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=a2)

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)  # or binary_crossentropy

    model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              verbose=0,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    return model,inputs,a2




X_test = X_train = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0],[1, 1]])
y_train = y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3,0]),num_classes=5)
model,inputs,outputs = build_and_train_mlp_network(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
print(model.summary())
model.predict(X_test)
```

and if you would like to get max class again from the compute graph

```py
class ArgMax(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ArgMax, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self,X):
        print(X)
        return K.argmax(X, axis=None)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {"name": self.__class__.__name__}
        base_config = super(Round, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

am = ArgMax()(outputs)
modelam=Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=[am,outputs])
clazzes,confidence = modelam.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: can you give more code about how to use map ? -------"or to map to characters you can use"

Comment: print(np.round(model.predict(X_test)))---------it is work for me,   but  i need   there are not same number in output array,    such as now  output is [1,2,2,4], there are same "2" in one output